# How to update Listview for each new entry at the bottom?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I am making an application with a chat and what I want to achieve is that for each new message, the `Listview` updates at the bottom. This is what I have tried:

```
 private ViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await viewModel.Connect();
        viewModel.RefreshScrollDown = () => {
            if (viewModel.Messages.Count > 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                    listMessages.ScrollTo(viewModel.Messages[viewModel.Messages.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, true);
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

**ListView:**

```
 <ListView
            x:Name="MessagesList"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
            SelectionMode="None" />
```

And when I change to `CollectionView`:

```
      <CollectionView
            x:Name="MessagesList"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
            SelectionMode="None" />
```

Comment: are you asking how to do you actually add new data to your listview?  Is your `ItemsSource` an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: My ItemSource is an ObservableCollection. Im asking how to scroll the listview to bottom when a new message is received.

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have?  What does it do (or not do)?

Comment: OnAppearing only happens when you navigate to the page.  If you are adding to your collection only on the same page, then that's why it's not working--you'll need to put that ScrollTo code in the same place where you add to your collection.

Comment: I'm testing now and RefreshScrollDown is never called.

Comment: I put the ScrollTo code in the same place where I add elements into the collection but the RefreshScrollDown is never called in debug.

Comment: You can also listen to when an item is added and use MessagingService to notify your code-behind that the list should scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add new messages to your `ItemSource` as they come in, then you can consider using the `CollectionView`，because it has an off-the-shelf property (`ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"`) that adjusts the scroll offset to keep the last item in the list displayed when new items are added.

You could look at [Control scroll position when new items are added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling#control-scroll-position-when-new-items-are-added).

Update :

in listview,your DataTemplate  maybe like:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid>
         ...
        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

when you use collectionview,it will be like:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
     ...
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

the more you could refer to [collectionview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout).

Comment: I have made the change from ListView to CollectionView and my application crashes with this error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: @dimioLt Could you show the codes which throw the exception ?

Comment: The application crashes 2 seconds after starting and the exception does not show me any line in which it has occurred. Is there any way to know clearly? I don't have much knowledge about debugging

Comment: @dimioLt Did it crash after changing the ListView? If so, you could display the codes of the page.

Comment: Yes, with ListView it works correctly but when changing to CollectionView it crashes. I updated the post with the code of ListView and CollectionView.

Comment: @dimioLt I think the issue is cause of your `ItemTemplate`,`CollectionView` has no concept of cells,so it don't need `ViewCell` element in its `DataTemplate`.

Comment: If I remove DataTemplate the app don't crash but the messages are not appearing fine. How can I use my DataTemplate without crashing?

Comment: @dimioLt You don't need to remove the `DataTemplate`, you just don't need to use the `ViewCell` in it.the example is like the update above.